# YAML special characters

Tags: yaml, packer

I have yaml which is use for a packer template. How can I write commands in order to be okay for YAML? Because I receive errors due to special characters like "|"?

```
    "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "inline": [
      "sudo yum update",
      "yum install -y net-tools",
      "sudo yum install -y wget",
      "sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose",
      "sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose",
      "sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose",
      "sudo yum install -y git",
      ],
    }
  ]
```

Comment: That's a very vague question, and your example shows JSON. Have a look at https://www.yaml.info/learn/quote.html. There you can learn pretty much everything about YAML quoting. Most important are characters at the beginning of the string, like `|` and `*`. Disclaimer: I'm the author of that page.

Answer (score 0):

\ as an escape character works in most cases *if used within quotation marks* (which should be fine if using a string, which is where most of your reserved characters will show up. Example:

```
- movies:
  - riseOfSkywalker:
    - titles:
      - "Star Wars\: Episode IX: The Rise of Skywalker"
```

This is finicky and I've had problems getting the colon to parse right even with this. I'm now informed that it simply isn't part of the specification; I've had it work before but apparently, it's not supported.

Comment: Escaping a `:` sign is invalid. Only certain characters are allowed to escape with a backslash in double quotes, as you can read above in the page I linked. There might be libraries accepting `\:`, but it is invalid.

Comment: I stand corrected! It's worked with parsers and linters I've used but I haven't read the specifications!